# Problem showing modelstate errors while using RenderPartialToString

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, partial-views

Im using the following code:

```
public string RenderPartialToString(ControllerContext context, string partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, TempDataDictionary tempData)
    {
        ViewEngineResult result = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, partialViewName);

        if (result.View != null)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
            {
                using (HtmlTextWriter output = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(context, result.View, viewData, tempData, output);
                    result.View.Render(viewContext, output);
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }
```

To return a partial view and a form through JSON. It works as it should, but as soon as I get modelstate errors my ValidationSummary does not show. The JSON only return the default form but it does not highlight the validation errors or show the validation summary.

Am I missing something?

This is how I call the RenderPartialToString:

```
string partialView = RenderPartialToString(this.ControllerContext, "~/Areas/User/Views/Account/ChangeAccountDetails.ascx", new ViewDataDictionary(avd), new TempDataDictionary());
```

Comment: Omar is correct but I just want to add that you need to manually transfer your model state over to the new ViewContext you've created.

Comment: Yep, i didn't explain why =P but jfar did, thx for the complement.

Comment: Excactly what do you mean by this, do you mean I have to transfer my `ModelState` into the `RenderPartialToString` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with a similar code:

All fix when added this lines:

```
// copy model state items to the html helper
                foreach (var item in context.Controller.ViewData.ModelState)
                    html.ViewData.ModelState.Add(item);
```

If i do a port to this particular scenario it ll be something like

```
    ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(context, result.View, viewData, tempData, output);

//Copy the ModelSate            
    foreach (var item in context.Controller.ViewData.ModelState)
    viewContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Add(item);

result.View.Render(viewContext, output);
```

Comment: Okay, I have tested the code, I think i'm missing something, I got this error:
`An item with the same key has already been added.`

Comment: mmm.. weird the original problem resides in ViewData as it does not contain the ModelStateDictionary, try to inspect the viewData at this line "ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(context, result.View, viewData, tempData, output);
" with a breakpoint, it should be empty, thats why i added the foreach that fill the ModelState of the new ViewContext.

Comment: Okay, im not sure how this can be of any help. But when I added { } around ModelState.Add it all worked.

Answer (score 3):

After spending too much time on this problem I saw that the `ModelState` items shouldn't be added to the `viewContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState`, it should be added to `viewContext.ViewData.ModelState`. After making this change the `ModelState` errors were being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to make it work:

```
foreach (var item in context.Controller.ViewData.ModelState)
{
    viewContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Add(item);
}
```

Not sure why I needed the { } 's..

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with all of the solutions presented in the above comments, so I refined it a bit just to be sure that it works appropriately in all possible cases:

```
foreach (var item in controllerContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState)
{
    if (item.Value.Errors.Any())
    {
        viewContext.ViewData.ModelState.Add(item);    
    }
}
```